# Finding Duplicates in a single column and return all other column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have a table with data that I would like to find any rows with a duplication Position # (one of my columns in the data).
I have written some code that is working but it does not allow me to see the additional Column/header information.

Data Table:

| MainItem | BomLevel | Position | ComponentItem | CompDesc | TotalQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 316006 | 1 | 10 | 500006 | Conv Kit | 1 |
| 316006 | 1 | 20 | 562060 | Battery | 4 |
| 316006 | 1 | 30 | VS147 | Charger | 1 |
| 316006 | 1 | 40 | 9970 | Red Pad | 1 |
| 316006 | 1 | 60 | 563844 | Blue Pad | 1 |
| 316006 | 1 | 60 | 512346 | Machine | 1 |

I would like to return:

| MainItem | BomLevel | Position | ComponentItem | CompDesc | TotalQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 316006 | 1 | 60 | 563844 | Blue Pad | 1 |
| 316006 | 1 | 60 | 512346 | Machine | 1 |

This is the code I currently know how to write:

```
select    
    a.MainItem
    , a.BomLevel
    , a.Position    
from reports.v_bom a    
where a.MainItem = '316006'    
group by a.MainItem, a.BomLevel, a.Position    
having Count (*) > 1
```

but this will only return:

| MainItem | BomLevel | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 316006 | 1 | 60 |

Comment: Syntax can vary by vendor. Please add your dbms and version to the question tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've only tagged `SQL` the following is ANSI SQL and will work in most modern RDBMS that support analytic window functions:

```
with c as (
    select *, Count(*) over(partition by mainitem, bomlevel, position) cnt
    from t
)
select * 
from c
where cnt > 1;
```